# Routing to SSR app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I am using create-react-app and just added SSR for same.

I just added a middleware to renderToString the react app.

But I am not sure about routing. Should it remain on client or on express(server). If it's on client it is not working. Every request is being served to home page. Quite fair by code I have written. Not sure though how to mend it to serve other pages and still keep the same setup.

Code is below

**server/index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import serverRenderer from './middleware/renderer';

const PORT = 3001;
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.use('^/$', serverRenderer);
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
router.use(express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    { maxAge: '30d' },
));
router.use('*', serverRenderer);
app.use(router);

...
```

**middleware/renderer.js**

```
import {createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

...

const history = createMemoryHistory({
  initialEntries: ['/', '/next', '/last'],
  initialIndex: 0
});

export default (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.url); //logs `/` for every route
};
```

Cannot understand what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it will always render the homepage is because you have the following snippet:

```
const history = createMemoryHistory({
  initialEntries: ['/', '/next', '/last'],
  initialIndex: 0
});`
```

If you change this to

```
const history = createMemoryHistory({
    initialEntries: [req.url],
    initialIndex: 0
});
```

inside your render function it should render the correct URL.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't work - I shifted these lines inside exported function.  I tried logging `req.url`  and history  inside my renderer. Both indicate url being hit as `/`. Pretty sure I am not hitting home page  but  something `localhost:3001/articles`

Comment: Meanwhile I updated my question to minimal code to highlight the problem  better.

Comment: I want your advice on another thing. This same setup loads `index.html` for every path. It first loads that component and then it renders server's index.html. So somewhere something must be wrong in these above lines. Please let me know if you need any more details. I am badly helpless here !

Comment: Can you make a new question for that with new code snippet? Ping me here when you have done that?

Comment: Actually this wasn't the case which I described. Server side routing seems okay, but client side routing is not in sync. Will post a detailed problem set for same.