# Routing not working after SSR

Tags: reactjs, express

This question in follow up of [Routing to SSR app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746787/routing-to-ssr-app)

**Problem statement** - When I run my server, it loads the homepage, then when I type `localhost:3001/about_us` in my browser it loads the component ( I can see it loading - fully ) and then it suddenly renders home page again.

`AboutUs` is an AsyncComponent loaded via react-loadable.

I have already shared the server side setup files on above link.

Structure of the project is below:

- build
- public
- server
- src ( react app)

Client code

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';
import store, { history } from './store';

import './index.css';
import './main.css';
import App from './containers/app';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

window.onload = () => {
    Loadable.preloadReady().then(() => {
        ReactDOM.hydrate(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                      <App />
                </ConnectedRouter>
            </Provider>,
             document.getElementById('root')
        );
    });
};
```

**src/store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createMemoryHistory';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

export const history = createHistory();

const initialState = {};
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];



const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);

export default store;
```

**containers/app/index.js**

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import { LoadingSuccess, getMetaData } from '../../reducers/homepage';


const AsyncHome = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "root" */'../public/home'),
  loading: () => <div>loading...</div>,
  modules: ['root']
});


const AsyncContactUs = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "contact-us" */'../public/contact-us'),
  loading: () => <div>loading...</div>,
  modules: ['contact-us']
});

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            path: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        this.props.LoadingSuccess();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        var path = ((nextProps.history || {}).location || {}).pathname;
        if (path && path != this.state.path && Constant.ignoreMetaTags.indexOf(path) == -1) {
            // this.props.getMetaData(path);
            // this.setState({
            //  path: path
            // });
        }
    }

    navigateTo(route) {
        if (route.length) {
            this.props.navigateTo(route);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated, navigateTo, errors, ForgotPasswordSuccess, forgotPasswordError, forgotPasswordSuccessMessage, metaDataPayload, metaDataError } = this.props;
        return (
            <Container>
                {this.setMetaTags()}
                <Header isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} navigateTo={navigateTo} />
                <View>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={() => <AsyncHome />} />
                        <Route path="/home" component={() => <h1>Home</h1>} />


                        <Route path="/contact_us" component={() => <AsyncContactUs />} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Authenticated} />
                    </Switch>
                </View>
                <Footer />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapsStateToProps = ({
  homepageReducer: { homepageLoaded, metaDataPayload, metaDataError },
    authReducer: {
    isAuthenticated,
        errors,
        forgotPasswordError,
        forgotPasswordSuccessMessage
  },
    contactUsReducer: { locations, error },
    location
}) => ({
        homepageLoaded,
        isAuthenticated,
        location,
        errors,
        forgotPasswordError,
        forgotPasswordSuccessMessage,
        metaDataPayload,
        metaDataError
    });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    navigateTo: route => dispatch(push(route)),
    LoadingSuccess: () => dispatch(LoadingSuccess()),
    ForgotPasswordSuccess: payload => dispatch(ForgotPasswordSuccess(payload))});

export default withRouter(connect(mapsStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

On debugging it calls LoadingSuccess from reducer as a last call maybe and then the home page is rendered. My guesses are following along client and server history mismatch But cannot somehow eliminate the problem in-hand.

**UPDATE -**

Server Side code -

index.js

import express from 'express';

```
import serverRenderer from './middleware/renderer';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const PORT = 3001;
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.use('^/$', serverRenderer);
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
router.use(express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    { maxAge: '30d' },
));
router.use('*', serverRenderer);
app.use(router);
Loadable.preloadAll().then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log('something bad happened', error);
        }

        console.log('listening on ' + PORT + '...');
    });
});
```

**renderer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import store from '../../src/store';
import {createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import manifest from '../../build/asset-manifest.json';
import App from '../../src/containers/app';
// import request from 'request';
import axios from 'axios';
var request = axios.create({
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const modules = [];
const extractAssets = (assets, chunks) => Object.keys(assets)
    .filter(asset => chunks.indexOf(asset.replace('.js', '')) > -1)
    .map(k => assets[k]);

export default (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl;
    const history = createMemoryHistory({
      initialEntries: [req.originalUrl],
      initialIndex: 0
    });
    // const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createMemoryHistory, store)

    try {
        if (req.originalUrl !== '/' && req.originalUrl.indexOf('[') === -1) {
            request.get('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/public/seo/pages' + url ).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.success){
                    // console.log('response.data', response.data);
                    const { title, meta_description, meta_keywords, noindex, additional_meta} = response.data.page;
                    console.log(title, meta_description, meta_keywords, noindex);
                    const additional_meta_string = additional_meta.map(function (item) {
                        return <meta key={item.name} name={item.name} content={item.content} property={item.property} />;
                    });
                    const metaString = `<title>${title}</title>
                                        <meta name="description" content=${meta_description} />
                                        <meta name="keywords" content=${meta_keywords} />
                                        ${noindex ? <meta name="robots" content="noindex" /> : null} ${additional_meta_string}`;

                    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build', 'index.html');
                    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error('err', err);
                            return res.status(404).end();
                        }
                        const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
                        const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                            sheet.collectStyles(<Provider store={store}>
                              <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                                  <Loadable.Capture report={m => modules.push(m)}>
                                       <App />
                                  </Loadable.Capture>
                              </ConnectedRouter>
                            </Provider>)
                        );
                        const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags();
                        const extraChunks = extractAssets(manifest, modules)
                        .map(c => `<script type="text/javascript" src="/${c}"></script><script>window.REDUX_STATE = ${reduxState};</script>`);
                            return res.send(
                                htmlData.replace(
                                        '</head>',
                                        `${styleTags}</head>`
                                    )
                                    .replace(/__OG_TITLE__/g, title)
                                    .replace(/__OG_DESCRIPTION__/g, meta_description)
                                    .replace(
                                    '<div id="root"></div>',
                                    `<div id="root">${body}</div>`
                                ).replace(
                                    '</body>',
                                    extraChunks.join('') + '</body>'
                                )
                            );
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('response.error', response.data.messages);
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
               console.log('API_ERROR', error);
               return error;
            });
        } else {
            const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build', 'index.html');
            fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('err', err);
                    return res.status(404).end();
                }
                const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
                const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                    sheet.collectStyles(<Provider store={store}>
                      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                          <Loadable.Capture report={m => modules.push(m)}>
                               <App />
                          </Loadable.Capture>
                      </ConnectedRouter>
                    </Provider>)
                );
                const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags();
                const reduxState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
                const extraChunks = extractAssets(manifest, modules)
                .map(c => `<script type="text/javascript" src="/${c}"></script><script>window.REDUX_STATE = ${reduxState};</script>`);
                    return res.send(
                        htmlData.replace(
                                '</head>',
                                `${styleTags}</head>`
                            ).replace(
                            '<div id="root"></div>',
                            `<div id="root">${body}</div>`
                        ).replace(
                            '</body>',
                            extraChunks.join('') + '</body>'
                        )
                    );
            });
        }

    } catch (e) {
      console.log('getInfo_ERROR', e);
      next(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your state is not in sync, which is exactly what leads to this problem. What you need to do is send the state of the redux store to the client and initialize that.

The following is what I do:

On the server:

```
res.write(
  `<script>window.__INITIALSTATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(
    store.getState()
  )};</script>`
)
```

to include the state in a script tag into the HTML.

Then on the client, you want to read that and set that as the initial state.

```
const initialState = window && window.__INITIALSTATE__ || {}
const store = createStore(
  config.redux.reducer,
  initialState,
  enhancer
);
```

In your case, you are still missing in src/store.js

**src/store.js**

```
 const initialState = window && window.REDUX_STATE || {};
```

Comment: adding `<!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.REDUX_STATE = __SERVER_REDUX_STATE__;
    </script> -->`  below `<div id="root"></div>`. 

Then on server `const reduxState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());`

`return res.send(
                htmlData.replace(
                    '<div id="root"></div>',
                    `<div id="root">${html}</div>`
                ).replace(
                    '</body>',
                    extraChunks.join('') + '</body>'
                ).replace(__SERVER_REDUX_STATE__, reduxState)`

It throws ref error

Comment: Reference error - __SERVER_REDUX_STATE__ is not defined.

Comment: But will this be required? Since on intial render of index.html itself it throws reference error for that variable.

Comment: It is required if you want me to solve your problem yes. You need to include an extra <script> tag in the HTML you send to the client.

Comment: Alright. It would have worked this way for sure but was wondering why not by other approach. Anyway, please ignore that and I can experiment this in my free time for placeholders fix. 
Moving forward ...
In my `store.js` I get `window is not defined` error by using the initial state as mentioned

Comment: Also, I have updated the server side code a bit. Accidently shared old code earlier. ( not much difference though)

Comment: I added a temporary check in store.js for window. 

`var initialState = {};
if ( typeof window !== 'undefined') {
     initialState = window.REDUX_STATE;
}
`

But the issue with routing is same.

Comment: Do you see the state in the REDUX_STATE in the HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165283/discussion-between-kushalvm-and-erwin-van-der-koogh).